# How to specify a specific connection (or the database name) for Yajra Datatables in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel-5, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm using Laravel 5 with Jajra/Datatables

The project use 3 databases, one is MySQL and 2 are commercial SQL databases.

The SQL databases have the tables with exactly same names.

If I want to display a table from MySql database I use in controller:

```
return  Datatables::of(DB::table('coeficientVR_VanzariNoi')
        ->get(['id','marca','model','capacitate','combustibil', 'caroserie', 'altaClasaSchimb', 'coeficient',
              ]))->make(true);
```

and it's working great!

How to specify a table from one of the the SQL databases?

I have models associated to them, and models have the connection specified.

Example for one of table which is named "version":

```
class version_Jato extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'sqlJato';
    protected $table = 'version';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vehicle_id';

....
```

So I need to specify the SQL database but I don't know how.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is SQL database?  SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already defined the `$connection` on each model you can query directly the model, i.e.:

```
return DataTables::eloquent(App\version_Jato::query())
    ->make();
```

You can read about it in the [yajra/datatables docs](http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/response-array).

Comment: Thank you sir!
How can I use  App\version_Jato::query() to join or left join with other tables?

Comment: Can I set an alias for the first model?

Comment: You can use joins if you define a relationship on the model like that: `App\version_Jato:::with('your_relationship')->get()` you can read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships. Or with a direct join: `App\version_Jato:::join(...)->select(...)->get();` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: Thank you for the directions, anyway nor select nor get() are not defined as methods for eloquent. I am thinking in this case to make the query statically and send the full collection with the view and renounce to Ajax loading.

Comment: They are defined on the query builder which is called by eloquent when you call a static method, if you want you can always start with `query()`, i.e.: `App\version_Jato::query()->select()-get();` should be the same.

Comment: If I do this:
Datatables::eloquent(version_Jato::query())
            ->select(['vehicle_id'])->get()
            ->make(true);

I get the folowing error: 

Method Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable::select does not exist.

What I wanted to say before was eloquent implementation of Yajra\DataTables

Comment: You moved a bracket: `Datatables::eloquent(version_Jato::query() ->select(['vehicle_id'])->get())->make(true);`